Geolocation Not Working in PWA After Bubblewrap TWA Generation
I've been working on creating a Trusted Web Activity for my Progressive Web App using Bubblewrap. Everything seems to be working fine except for the geolocation functionality, which stops working after the TWA is generated. Here are the steps I followed:

Used Bubblewrap to generate the TWA.
Used .well-known/assetlinks.json to link the PWA and the TWA.

**Problem:
**
Before generating the TWA, the geolocation functionality in my PWA was working perfectly. After deploying the TWA, the geolocation functionality is no longer working. When I try to use geolocation, I don't get any response or permissions dialog from the app.
**What I've Tried:
**
Ensured that the PWA works correctly with geolocation when accessed directly from a browser.
Verified that the .well-known/assetlinks.json file is correctly configured and accessible.
Checked the permissions in the Android manifest file generated by Bubblewrap to ensure ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION are included.
**Question:
**
Why is the geolocation not working in the TWA generated by Bubblewrap, and how can I resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
